# How to suppress native runtime code exception popup

Tags: c#, android, maui

When I'm debugging my MAUI app on Android I frequently get this unactionable popup.

[image: popup]

My question is 'not' about what's causing it (I have a repeatable test case to inject the fault). I want to *suppress* it because there's no line to break on for a stack trace or anything else. It's perfectly useless.

I've tried setting **Tools\Options\Debugging\General\Enable Just My Code** and have zeroed out the **Break When Thrown** options in the **Exception Settings**. It still happens.

[image: Break When Thrown settings]

I also made sure to set a handler for any unhandled exceptions in the `AppDomain` ruling out the possibility of it being caused by an exception not being caught where it's thrown.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var exceptionType = e.ExceptionObject.GetType().Name;
            Debug.Fail(exceptionType);
        };

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += OnAssemblyLoaded;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

---

**Example**

Here's one specific case that illustrates the bigger issue.

I know that on my Android 12 physical test device, this will occur every first time the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert` method is called after starting up the app. Instead of halting execution on the `Debug.Assert` as it does on subsequent passes (and which would be helpful for debugging), it pops up the message and doesn't halt on the line.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (!_loaded)
    {
        _loaded = true;
        Debug.Assert(DeviceInfo.VersionString != "12", "Version 12 first time only bug.");
    }
}
```

**Problem "solved" (...almost)**

I added my `System.Diagnostics.TraceListener` to `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners` and now when this occurs I can break and get a call stack for "my" code this way.

```
class TraceListenerEx : TraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string message) { }
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (message.Contains("Microsoft.Maui.FontManager", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        { // N O O P 
        }
        else
        {
            switch (message.Replace("Fail: ", string.Empty).Trim())
            {
                case "Version 12 first time only bug.":
                    // Break here for stack trace
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the popup (when it appears) always does so *first*, before this breakpoint, really getting in the way of progress.

---

So, if anyone has any ideas about *how to **suppress** the useless popup* please share.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question but do you mean that you need preprocessor directives? I dont see them in your code, also have you set the debugger to Android? Perhaps I missunderstand you.

Comment: The aim of setting of `Break When Thrown` for exceptions, or using the platform-agnostic `System.Diagnostics.Debug` namespace to test a condition using `Debug.Assert(condition)` is the same either way: the debugger should pause execution on that line in order to examine the call stack and determine what the problem is. But what's happening here is that the debugger pauses execution during startup, says "something went wrong" in the _native_ code stack without any useful info whatsoever as to the calling line.  The debugger itself is working fine across all platforms.